# Sending message from a application on one mobile device to another application on another device

Tags: android

Hi I want to send message from one application (which will be installed on android mobile) to
another application (which will be installed on another mobile). This means

One mobile ------------sends message-------- >to another mobile.

Similarly I want second mobile to send----------message ----- to first mobile.

If I use sms to send message I think it will be saved in the sms box and so the user can read
the message. I want to hide the message . So is there any way I can send message directly from
one application to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent saving sms to inbox, you can abort broadcast:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // ...
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ...
        if( smsIsMine() ) {
            // Do something with  sms
            this.abortBroadcast();
        } 
    }
}
```

You also need to set the priority of SmsReceiver the highest possible priority in your AndroidManifest.xml as below:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
    <!-- ... -->
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Let me check it.